# Where does the name “Setup Wizard” come from?

Tags: wizard

A *wizard* is this step-by-step assistant for installations, but also WinZip archival.

Where does the name *wizard* originate from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an English Language question not a User Experience one.

Comment: @JonW What about moving it to the english language stack exchange?

Comment: Back in the old days, we used to have to perform various rituals and spells to successfully install software on a platform. As this process became automated, the installer software that guided users and performed the rituals became known as 'wizards'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a question for the english subdomain since this has nothing to do with ux.

However; if you take a look at synonyms for Wizard

https://www.synonyms.com/synonym/wizard

You have a few words for example: friend, lead, supporter etc.

But it could also be seen as something that performs "magic". Back in the days, installing something just clicking "next" and chosing a few options were probably considered magic. Today we take such things for granted.

According to wikipedia [1] and the link to English stackexchange as I mentioned [2]

> Before the 1990s, "wizard" was a common term for a technical expert, somewhat akin to "hacker."

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software) [1]
2. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65728/origin-of-the-term-wizard-in-computing [2]